# Unclosed elements <pre> and <code> in an answer

Tags: bug, markdown

Have a look at the bottom of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/261262/1128737). You can see that the code formatting continues even after the end of the answer. This is because the elements `<pre>` and `<code>` are unclosed for some reason, [as seen by the W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=https://stackoverflow.com/a/261262/1128737&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator/1.3%20http://validator.w3.org/services). Note also how the three last lines of the code block are not visible. Here's a picture from my browser (Firefox 28.0):

[image: Picture of the glitch]

To me, [the Markdown source of the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/72504e78-c721-4551-81f8-fa7bd8b86066/view-source) seems fine, so the question is - what is causing this glitch?